# How to control the whole margin of a graph(including plot area and title/footnote) in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, margin, lattice

I am using both the lattice and ggplots package to create scatterplot in R. 
when using lattice package, I can contrl the whole graph size (including plot area and title/footnote) with below codes:

```
xyplot(
  test2 ~ test1, 
  data     = in.data, 
  groups   = SEX,
  #title
  main     = textGrob(c("This is the title", "\nThis is the sub-title"), 
                  x = unit(c(left.margin,left.margin), "inches"),
                  just  = "left", 
                  gp    = gpar(fontsize = c(title.font, title.font), lineheight=1.5)),
  #footnote
  sub = textGrob(paste(footnote1,Sys.time(),sep="\n"), 
             x = unit(c(left.margin), "inches"), 
             y = unit(c(bottom.margin), "inches"),
             just = c("left", "bottom"),
             gp = gpar(fontsize = footer.font, lineheight=0.9))
# Figure margins
lattice.options = list(layout.widths = leftright.margin, 
layout.heights = topbottome.margin)
)
```

You can see that the lattice.options can control the whole figure size including title and footnote.
while with ggplot2, I create a plot use qplot(...) then control plot margin with:

```
theme(plot.margin=unit(x=c(top.margin,right.margin,bottom.margin,left.margin),
units="inches"))
```

then  add title and footnote with arrangeGrob.

```
 g <- arrangeGrob(myplot, main=textGrob(c(title1, title2), 
                                   x = unit(c(left.margin,left.margin), "inches"),
                                   y = unit(c(-top.margin,-top.margin), "inches"),
                                   just  = "left", 
                                   gp    = gpar(fontsize = c(title.font, title.font), 
                                                fontface=c("plain","plain"),
                                                lineheight = 1.5)),
             sub = textGrob(paste(footnote1,Sys.time(),sep="\n"), 
                            x = unit(c(left.margin), "inches"), 
                            y = unit(c(bottom.margin), "inches"),
                            just = c("left", "bottom"),
                            gp = gpar(fontsize = footer.font,lineheight=0.9)))

g
```

In this way, the plot.margin only control the plot area, not control title and footnote. So how should I do to control the both plot area and title area in ggplot2 (just like lattice package)?
If the answer is not, in this case I will prefer lattice pakcage.